# Audi A4 Going Into Limp Mode

Tags: fuel-system, audi, fuel-pump

I have an Audi A4 B7 and as soon as I bought it off the lot, it started going into limp mode around 3k RPM. it doesn't go any higher than that even when I rev it.

- I have replaced the cam follower
- I have replaced an exhaust hose (unrelated)

It throws an engine code every once in a while `P2293` which means it's a bad HPFP.

It is very intermittent when it does this, so sometimes it won't do it for a few weeks, and then sometimes it does this for a few weeks on and off a few times a day.

If the code says it is the HPFP, and you guys think its the HPFP, then I guess that's 600$ down the drain.

I am just wanting to make sure it couldn't be another cheaper fix that isn't the HPFP.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If it went into limp mode as soon as you drove it off the lot take it back as they sold you a defective car!

Comment: Is the *sensor* the right one? Please see Youtube's [error code P2293 (RESOLVED)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE3708vNZlE) where the fuel pump and the cam follower had already been replaced. It also says the sympton was cutting off the turbo, which can seem like limp mode. The same thing happens with VW engines when the EGR valve is blocked - the turbo cuts out until the engine is restarted, and without turbo the engine does not pull. It limps, but is not in "limp mode" which only allows you to creep the car to safety, and stays until the fault code is cleared.

Comment: ...so I also suggest the culprit could be the EGR valve. What you describe is not "limp mode" which only allows the car to be manoeuvred, and stays like that until the error code is cleared. The turbo cut-out limits the engine power until it is restarted, and that is what happens when the EGR valve is choked. The behaviour is if you accelerate gently it's all ok, until you apply more power, at which point the turbo is disabled. There is enough power to drive around town, but not enough to hold a cruising speed or an uphill run.